# Passing serializer data in Django httpresponseredirect

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, httpresponse, http-redirect

Here is my initial login view:

```py
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This gives the below results after login:

[image]

But then to prevent form resubmission, I changed from `Response` to `HttpResponseRedirect`:

```py
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login',serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)) # new
```

But it gives me the error:

```bash
TypeError: unhashable type: 'ReturnDict'
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
import json

class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('login'),
            json.dumps(serializer.data),
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

Comment: Is there a way I could get the data on the DRF form?

Comment: @sajeyksmwangi does it help? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/